# Why tmux does not respect terminal color settings?

Tags: terminal, colors, zsh, tmux

I'm using `alacritty` terminal emulator and ZSH shell. When I customize my `alacritty` config so it contains light background and specific color scheme, it works allright. But as soon as I create `tmux` session, the color scheme changes to black background.

Does `tmux` come with its own color scheme that needs to be overriden? I do have this in my config:

```
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Which is what everyone says that it solves all issues with mismatched colors. I can't seem to tell `tmux` to use my terminal color settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).